# Are Indifference Curve graphs continuous given the preferential definition of continuity?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

Assume the relation $\succeq$ is continuous (by the preferential definition). Does this mean the graph of Indifference Curves are continuous?

Since $\sim$ satisfies the definition for $\succeq$, we have the IC follow the preferential definition. But what about the topological definition?

I think it does, and here's what I have done. Please verify!

> Rephrasing the question: Given $I = \{x : x \sim y\}$ equipped with the standard topology, consider $f : I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x) = x$. How do you show $f$ is continuous? (**Note.** I don't know if it is true, I have assumed it to be true and tried to show that it indeed is.)
>
> *Proof.* An arbitrary $S \subseteq I$ when closed does not violate the continuity, so for any other $S$ which is open, $f^{-1}(S) = S$ is open. $\blacksquare$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with a "continuous graph"? The $f$ you define is the identity function on $I$. This function is trivially continuous but has nothing to do with ICs.

Comment: @VARulle Well, so if you plot a particular IC, say IC(y) = {x : x ~ y}, then the function IC(y) is continuous. Note that I am considering the function IC and not a binary relation. I know the identity function is immediate, but isn't it the plot of IC the identity function I wrote?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus as you define it, $IC(y)$ produces a set (the set of bundles indifferent to $y$) and not a single bundle. This means that $IC(.)$ is a **correspondence** and not a function. You want to show that $IC$ is upper and lower hemi-continuous?

Comment: @tdm Sorry, that's my fault. So I was essentially trying to find out if while plotting the Indifference Curve, I can draw it without having to lift my pen(cil). While it is a set, we can represent the "plot" by defining f : {x : x ~ y} to R$^n$ given by f(x) = x. Isn't it so? Because, if we can represent it via the function f, we can prove (as I did in the post) that we can draw the curve without having to lift my pencil. I hope I was able to frame my question better this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To follow up on the answer of @VARulle let me give you some conditions for which the indifference curve is path connected.

The argument can also be found in the book [Mathematical Methods and Models for Economists](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521585295) by Angel de la Fuente.

Preferences are **monotone** if $x > y$ implies $x \succ y$ and that preferences are **continuous** if $x_n \succeq y_n$, $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ imply $x \succeq y$.

Let us limit ourselves to the space $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$ of strictly positive bundles. For some $a \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}$ consider the indifference curve $I(a) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}| x \sim a\}$.

**Theorem** If preferences are monotone and continuous then for $a \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}$,  the set $I(a)$ is path-connected.

As being path-connected is a topological property, it suffices to show that there is a homeomorphism between $I(a)$ and a path-connected set. For this, we will take the set $\Delta$:
$$
\Delta = \{z \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}: \sum_i z_i = 1\}
$$
This set is path-connected as any two elements in $\Delta$ can be connected by the line segment that has these points as endpoints.

Consider the radial projection function $f: I(a) \to \Delta$ defined as:
$$
f(x) = \dfrac{x}{\sum_i x_i}
$$
As we restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$, the function $f$ is well defined. It is easy to see that $f$ is continuous. To show that it is a homeomorphism, we have to show that it is a bijection and that $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.

First, to show that $f$ is onto. let $z \in \Delta$ and consider the ray $\alpha z$ with $\alpha > 0$. Then for $\alpha$ large enough, we have $\alpha z > a$, so by monotonicity $\alpha z \succ a$. Also for $\alpha > 0$ small enough, we have $\alpha z < a$ so, by monotonicity, $a \succ \alpha z$.

Let $\alpha^\ast = \inf \{\alpha| \alpha z \succ a\}$ which is well defined by the argument above. Then by continuity $\alpha^\ast z \succeq a$. Also for all $\alpha < \alpha^\ast$ we have $a  \succeq \alpha z$  so again by continuity $a \succeq \alpha^\ast z$. This shows that $\alpha^\ast z \sim a$ or equivalently $\alpha^\ast z \in I(a)$. Defining $x = \alpha^\ast z$, gives that $x \sim a$ and $h(x) = z$, so $h$ is onto.

To show that $f$ is a bijection, let $f(x) = f(y) = z$. We need to show that $x = y$. We have:
$$
\dfrac{x}{\sum_i x_i} = \dfrac{y}{\sum_i y_i} = z.
$$
As such,
$$
x \sum_i y_i = y \sum_i x_i,
$$
which shows that $x$ and $y$ are proportional to each other, i.e.,
$$
\alpha x = \beta y.
$$
if $\alpha = \beta$ then $x$ and $y$ are identical, so either $\alpha > \beta$ or vice versa. But then by monotonicity $y \succ  \frac{\beta}{\alpha} y = x$ or vice versa, which gives a contradiction with $x, y \in I(a)$.

Finally, to see that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, let $z \in \Delta$ and take any sequence $z_n \to z$. It suffices to show the existence of a subsequence $z_{k_n}$ such that $h^{-1}(z_{k_n}) \to h^{-1}(z)$.

Define $x_n = h^{-1}(z_n)$ and $x = h^{-1}(z)$. Then:
$$
\alpha_n x_n = z_n.
$$
with $\alpha_n = \frac{1}{\sum_i x_{i,n}}$ also we have that:
$$
\alpha x = z,
$$
with $\alpha = \frac{1}{\sum_i x_i}$. It suffices to show that there is a subsequence for which $x_{k_n} \to x$.

If $\{\alpha_n\}$ is bounded, there is a convergent subsequence $\alpha_{k_n} \to \alpha^\ast$. If $\alpha^\ast = 0$ then as $z_n \to z$ there is an $n_k$ large enough such that $x_{n_k} = \frac{z_{n_k}}{\alpha_{n_k}} > \frac{z}{\alpha} = x$ which would contradict $x_{n_k} \sim x$. As such, $\alpha^\ast > 0$ and:
$$
x_{k_n} = \frac{z_{k_n}}{\alpha_{k_n}} \to \frac{z}{\alpha^\ast} = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha^\ast} x.
$$
Then as $x_{k_n} \sim x$ for all $n$, by continuity, $x \sim \frac{\alpha}{\alpha^\ast}x$ which can only hold (by monotonicity) if $\alpha^\ast = \alpha$. This shows that  $x_n \to x$.

If $\alpha_n > 0$ is unbounded, then there is a subsequence $\alpha_{k_n} \to \infty$. Then along this subsequence (as $z_{k_n} \to z$) we have
$$
x_{k_n} = \frac{z_{k_n}}{\alpha_{k_n}} \to 0,
$$
So for $n$ large enough $x_{k_n} < x$ which means that $x \succ x_{k_n}$ which again contradicts $x_{k_n} \sim x$. This shows that $f^{-1}$ is continuous $\square$.

Comment: Ah, that's a very well-explained proof. I assumed monotonicity (non-satiation), and was wondering how could a curve be not path-connected when an IC is continuous (and non-"thick"). With these assumptions, I chose the function without realizing the potential issue which is the domain is then only a subset of $X$ that is $I$.

Comment: This^ takes into account the case when $|I| < \infty$, as in VARulle's example. I will accept this answer once I read the complete argument, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: The theorem states that continuity of preference implies path-connectivity. I wonder if the converse is also true.

Answer (score 7):

Given your last comment above it seems that what you are really asking is whether the indifference sets of a continuous preference relation on $\mathbb R^n_+$ are [path-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness). The answer is *No*. Let $n=1$ and let the preference relation be represented by $u(x)=(1-x)^2$. Then the indifference set e.g. for $u=1$ is $\{0\}\cup\{2\}$, which is not path-connected.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I assumed monotonicity (non-satiation) and was wondering how could a curve be not path-connected when an IC is continuous (and non-"thick"). With these assumptions, I chose the identity function without realizing the potential issue which is the domain is then only a subset of $X$ that is $I$. (This takes into account the case when $|I| < \infty$ as in your example.)

Comment: **Def.** *Thick* Preferences are said to have *thick* ICs if $\exists$ at least one bundle $A \in X$ and an open ball $B(A)$ around $A$ such that $A′ \sim A$ for every $A′ \in B(A)$. [[Courtesy](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/13134/33107)]

Comment: I am sorry although your answer was extremely helpful, I will have to accept the other answer as it clarifies a few more questions I had, including this.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus, no problem!